# how to get filename from TkInter filedialog.askopenfile from a button command

Tags: python, function, button, tkinter, command

I'm quite new to python, and even more new to Tkinter. 
Sorry in advance for any obvious mistake I might be doing here ...

```
class application():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        frameCSV = LabelFrame(self.root)

        Button(frameCSV, text="browse csv", command= self.browseCSV)

        Label(frameCSV,text=csvFilename ,bg='white').grid(row =1,column=1)

    def browseCSV(self):
        global csvFilename
        csvFilename = filedialog.askopenfilename(   initialdir="/Volumes/", title="select the file", filetypes=[("CSV files", ".csv"),("all files", "*.*")] )
```

The `frameCSV` is a frame within my root window. I'd like to add inside this frame a `Label` with the returned path of the selected file.

But it doesn't work!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/guillaume/Downloads/uploader_v1_0_200312.py", line 106, in <module>
    f=application()
  File "/Users/guillaume/Downloads/uploader_v1_0_200312.py", line 70, in __init__
    Label(frameCSV,text=csvFilename ,bg='white').grid(row =1,column=1)
NameError: name 'csvFilename' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong? 
I don't get why the function doesn't pass the PATH to the `Label` to display it.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the label to be updated once a file is selected in `browseCSV()`, you need to associate a `StringVar` to the label and then update it inside `browseCSV()`:

```
class application():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.csvFilename = StringVar()  # use instance variable
        ...
        Label(frameCSV, textvariable=self.csvFilename, bg='white').grid(row=1, column=1)
        ...

    def browseCSV(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/Volumes/", title="select the file", 
                                              filetypes=[("CSV files", ".csv"),("all files", "*.*")])
        if filename:
            # a filename is selected, so update the label via StringVar
            self.csvFilename.set(filename)
```

Comment: thank you . I did exactly what you advised, and it works perfectly fine .

Answer (score 0):

however, i have this message when doing the build in SublimeText :
objc[3025]: Class FIFinderSyncExtensionHost is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FinderKit.framework/Versions/A/FinderKit (0x7fff85a04cd0) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FileProvider.framework/OverrideBundles/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride (0x10c6e1cd8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

does this mean anything i should worry about ?